# Router doesn't trigger onMatched callback when refreshing page in browser

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have an application with a RootComponent that contains two nested Components. One of these two Components, called UserComponent, displays a FlexibleColumnLayout and has a route with two URL parameters defined:

```
{
    "pattern": "detail/{objectId}/detailDetail/{treeObjectId}/{layout}",
    "name": "detailDetail",
    "target": [
        "list",
        "detail",
        "detailDetail"
    ],
    "greedy": true
}
```

Then, I try to access the respective URL parameters in the Controller like this:

```
onInit: function() {
    console.log("onInit() DetailController");
    // ...
    this.oRouter = this.getOwnerComponent().getRouter();
    this.oRouter.getRoute("list").attachMatched(this._onUrlMatched, this);
    this.oRouter.getRoute("detail").attachMatched(this._onUrlMatched, this);
    this.oRouter.getRoute("detailDetail").attachMatched(this._onUrlMatched, this);
},

_onUrlMatched: function(oEvent) {
    console.log("onUrlMatched()");
    // Fetch URL parameters...
    // Do something with the URL parameters...
},
```

The behaviour I observe is as follows:

- When I expand the FlexibleColumnLayout by navigating through the Routes step by step (list, detail, detailDetail), the `_onUrlMatched` callbacks are correctly fired and the current URL parameters are successully parsed.
- But when I reload the page, the `_onUrlMatched` callbacks are not called, even though the `onInit()` functions of all related Controllers are executed. The same happens when I paste the full URL in a new browser tab.

I already found an [official sample project](https://github.com/flovogt/ui5con20-ui5-routing/tree/main) with nested Components where the behavior is similar to what I desire. However, the example doesn't use a FlexibleColumnLayout and I see no difference in the manifest.xml or Controller files to my implementation.

Why are the callbacks not fired when I reload the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of digging, I found the solution to the problem. It turned out that the router configuration in the `manifest.xml` was wrong. I had to change the configuration from

```
"routing": {
    "config": {
        "routerClass": "sap.f.routing.Router",
        "viewType": "XML",
        "viewPath": "com.demo.admin.view",
        "controlId": "flexibleColumnLayout",
        "async": true,
        "transition": "slide"
    },
    //...
}
```

into

```
"routing": {
    "config": {
        "routerClass": "sap.f.routing.Router",
        "type": "View",
        "viewType": "XML",
        "path": "com.demo.admin.view",
        "controlId": "flexibleColumnLayout",
        "async": true,
        "transition": "slide"
    },
    //...
}
```

I found out by comparing my current project to [this sample project](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/entity/sap.f.tutorial.fiori2/sample/sap.f.tutorial.fiori2.09).

---

For completeness, this is my `index.html` file for which this solution is working:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height: 100%">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Demo Admin</title>

    <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
        src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
        data-sap-ui-theme="sap_horizon"
        data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{
            "com.demo.admin": "./"
        }'
        data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex"
        data-sap-ui-oninit="module:sap/ui/core/ComponentSupport"
        data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
        data-sap-ui-async="true"
        data-sap-ui-frameOptions="trusted">
    </script>
</head>

<body class="sapUiBody sapUiSizeCompact">
    <div data-sap-ui-component
        data-name="com.demo.admin"
        data-height="100%"
        data-id="container"
        data-settings='{"id" : "rootComponent"}'
        style="height: 100%">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

And this is my `App.view.xml` file:

```
<mvc:View
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    xmlns="sap.f"
    xmlns:m="sap.m"
    controllerName="com.demo.admin.controller.App"
    displayBlock="true"
    height="100%">

    <FlexibleColumnLayout
        id="flexibleColumnLayout"
        backgroundDesign="Solid"
        stateChange=".onStateChanged"
        layout="{/layout}" />

</mvc:View>
```